# JavaScript - After deleteRow of the last row, can't move up through the table properly

Tags: javascript, html-table, tablerow

After I highlight and delete the last row of the table, I can't move up. It seems to just go back and forth until I delete another row. After the first deleteRow, it works after deleting the odd numbered row. It gets stuck again after deleting an even numbered row. Last rows only.

So I know it's probably something to do with my even numbered rows.

[image: Album Listing Table]

I know after deleting the even numbered last row, the findLastHighlight() function returns "undefined".

In the moveUp() function, if the variable newHighlightedRow is assigned undefined, it will always go to the 1st row.

```
let newHighlightedRow = (lastHighlightedRow == 1)  ? 
            (allTableRows.length - 1) : (lastHighlightedRow - 2);
```

```
function moveUp(e) {
  let lastHighlightedRow = findLastHighlight();
  let allTableRows = [...document.querySelectorAll(".track_row")];

  let newHighlightedRow = (lastHighlightedRow == 1) ?
    (allTableRows.length - 1) : (lastHighlightedRow - 2);

  if (!lastHighlightedRow) {
    allTableRows[0].classList.add("selected_album_row");
    allTableRows[0].scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "nearest",
      inline: "center"
    });
  } else {
    if (lastHighlightedRow % 2 == 0) {
      allTableRows[newHighlightedRow].classList.add("selected_album_row");
      allTableRows[newHighlightedRow].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "nearest",
        inline: "center"
      });
    } else {
      allTableRows[newHighlightedRow].style.backgroundColor = "aquamarine";
      allTableRows[newHighlightedRow].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "nearest",
        inline: "center"
      });
    }
  }

}
```

```
function findLastHighlight() {
  let lastRowIndex;
  let allTableRows = [...document.querySelectorAll(".track_row")];
  let evenTableRows = allTableRows.filter(allTableRow => allTableRow.rowIndex % 2 == 0);
  let oddTableRows = allTableRows.filter(allTableRow => allTableRow.rowIndex % 2 != 0);

  oddTableRows.forEach((oddTableRow) => {
    if (oddTableRow.classList.contains("selected_album_row")) {
      oddTableRow.classList.remove("selected_album_row");
      lastRowIndex = oddTableRow.rowIndex;
    }
  });
  evenTableRows.forEach((evenTableRow) => {
    if (evenTableRow.style.backgroundColor == "aquamarine") {
      evenTableRow.style.backgroundColor = "";
      lastRowIndex = evenTableRow.rowIndex;
    }
  });
  return lastRowIndex;
}
```

Is my issue in the moveUp function or the newHighlightedRow variable?

https://jsfiddle.net/donfontaine12/6wnvp0sz/6/

Sorry, about the code being overly complicated. I'm just trying things out. Any assistance will be appreciated.

PS: Please ignore that the 1st and last rows are sometimes highlighted at the same time. That doesn't happen on my actual website.

Thank you.

Comment: In the jsfiddle you provided, the deletion doesn't work correctly either..

Comment: It deletes the row from the table as least visually. Are you referring to the code? I added this code: `allTableRows.splice(rowIndexForDeletion - 1,1); ` but commented it out because it doesn't change much.

Comment: What I meant is for example if you delete Track No 15, it will delete Track No 17 instead.

Comment: Oh, no, it renumbers all the tracks. You can disable it if you want. It's the function renumberAllTracks()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed it (still not sure if this is what you want)

Basically the problem came from this in findLastHighlight function:

```
evenTableRows.forEach((evenTableRow) => {
    if (evenTableRow.style.backgroundColor == "aquamarine") {
      evenTableRow.style.backgroundColor = "";
      lastRowIndex = evenTableRow.rowIndex;
    }
  });
```

so you look for highlighted row only in rows that are even and you don't take into account the odd rows that's why move up doesn't work when you delete an element

doing this instead

```js
allTableRows.forEach((evenTableRow) => {
    if (evenTableRow.style.backgroundColor == "aquamarine") {
      evenTableRow.style.backgroundColor = "";
      lastRowIndex = evenTableRow.rowIndex;
    }
  });
```

seems to fix it.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eb4pm7qd/1/).

Comment: Wow, thanks. I think you fixed it. I've been trying for weeks to fix it and I knew it would be a simply change. Thank you.